# Will a Modem connected to a UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supply) prevent loss of internet connection during a power outage?

Tags: internet

If i power the modem (the gateway to the internet) with a UPS, will it prevent loss of internet connection during a power outage? Or is this not possible (I don't know what else needs to be powered on beyond the modem). The case assumes that the ISP also doesn't lose power/runs on a generator when power outage occurs.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Put your main modem, and main router, and (if possible) your desktop computer all on a decent UPS.

In the event of a power failure, turn off the main computer after about 2 minutes of the failure, and a decent UPS should keep your network going for a couple of hours.

I do precisely as above here in my home office. Laptops have batteries, I turn the Desktop Off, and I have Internet for a couple of hours.

Very workable and having a UPS for this saves a lot of aggravation.

Answer (score 1):

Real world data:  Some days ago we had a 2 minute outage.  The modem and router are on the UPS, nothing dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I have both the TV and the router to the UPS. Power goes out and the router resets, but (and this is the weirdest part) I can keep watching TV for more than ten minutes. Both connected to the same power strip.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).